# Can I insert a button to take me straight to the bottom of my Wiki page?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I am currently building out a Wiki page that lists a very long set of items which takes forever to scroll through. Is there a button/link I can insert in to the page/code that will allow someone to go straight to the bottom? Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert an in-page anchor/bookmark
You could place this at the top:

```
<a href="#bottom">Go to bottom of page</a>
```

And then at the bottom create some sort of element with that ID:

```
<p id="bottom">Bottom of page</p>
```

Comment: The <a href="#bottom">Go to bottom of page</a> portion of this code just shows up as text on the page. Could it be the positioning within the page?

Comment: In this example it will show up as text, but it doesn't need to be a paragraph, I just wrote that for this example. It could just as easily be an empty <span> with the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code for the same

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
});
```

It will take you to bottom of your page

Answer (score 0):

Yes just add `<a name="#anything"></a>` to where you want to link to, and for the link type Click `<a href="#TheSameThing">here</a>`

Source: http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm